# How to code 2D segment tree?

Tags: data-structures, segment-tree

I was solving the problem `http://www.spoj.com/problems/LIS2/` on spoj. I tried for days but
could not come up with a solution  that could pass(time wise). Then I googled and found
people talking about `2D segment tree`.I searched a lot but could not find a descent  explanation.Is there any other solution to this problem ??
Also on topcoder i found people say this problem is similar to `www.spoj.com/problems/NICEDAY`.I had solved this problem way long back and that time I even did not know `1D segment tree`.
So can anyone suggest some solution to `LIS2` preferably with `2D segment tree`.

PS: I am not looking for codes please don't post codes a broad explanation of implementation
and space/time complexity of data structure will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this link : http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree

Although the page is in Russian, but Google Translate would be good enough.
This page explains the 1-D segment tree first. On the bottom, there is a section titled 'The two-dimensional tree segments in its simplest form' which would give you the required explanation.